# Calculate length and circumference based on bead size

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm working on a tool, it will have a simple size reference. I'm trying to create a formula with 3 variables.

```
x = bead size (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 mm)
y = length on string
z = circumference of chain
```

Suppose I need a 20 inch chain in length (y), using a beadsize 8mm (x), how would i calculate the circumference?

The end result would be for me to just add these numbers in excel and I'd get any possible option.

I do of course know the circumference = π × diameter.

Probably an easy question for the wizzards here, but I'm struggling;-)

Edit: I added an image that I made to clarify, hope that helps. Thank you.

[length or circumference needed, based on variable beadsize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvhRX.jpg)

Comment: Chain length is not circumference? Can you please clarify.

Comment: As in the previous comment, the circumference is the chain length, ergo you use your equation to determine the diameter, not vice versa.

Comment: Correct. Circumference is not the same as the length of a chain. If you'd take a piece of cord that is 10mm thick and a piece of cord that is 10cm thick, both 1 meter in length. The circumference is not even close.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, at a moment of clarity, I figured it was actually very easy.
All I had to do was subtract half the beadsize from the radius and use the known formula. In retrospect I cannot believe it had me confused for this long;-)

```
So, length became: 
r = C/2π
L = 2π × (r + 0.5*beadsize)

Or vice versa when the length is known, circumference is:
C = 2π × (r - 0.5*beadsize)
```